# R: Overcoming leaflet limitation

Tags: r, leaflet

I've started using leaflet put large circles on a map where clusters of failures occur in Europe. Its just playing around at present. I have 1.2 million rows for 6 months worth of data

I use the below code to cluster but it seems to not draw anything after 10k points. I don't really need it to go down to individual points, maybe it can be clustered up to 15 or 20 items. Can anyone suggest to me how to remedy the situation?

```
sample <- head(ex, 9500)  

leaflet(sample) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds(0, 60, 20, 70) %>%  
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

Answer (score 3):

`library(mapview)` is able to plot up to 4 million points (depending on machine obviously). Here's a reproducible example with ~ 1.3 million points:

```
library(mapview)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)

### blow diaminds up a bit
big <- data.frame(diamonds[rep(seq_len(nrow(diamonds)), 25),])
big$cut <- as.character(big$cut)
big$color <- as.character(big$color)
big$clarity <- as.character(big$clarity)

### provide some random positions
big$x <- rnorm(nrow(big), 0, 10)
big$y <- rnorm(nrow(big), 0, 10)
coordinates(big) <- ~x+y
proj4string(big) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

### view it
mapview(big)
```

This will take a while to load (on my machine about 30 secs), but then everything will be very responsive.

Note that this is functional, but there are less options for decorating points. I.e. no color or size mapping. On the upside, you will get full information in popups for all points about your underlying data frame.

Note also that **mapview** is designed to work with spatial classes (hence the `coordinates` and `proj4string` calls in the example), so you need to make sure you have a valid Spatial* object as provided by `library(sp)`.

Comment: Hi @TimSalabim, when i run your code it produces the map but not any points on the map. Maybe its browser related. With this method are you able to group points together into a cluster

Comment: No, no clustering. Try installing the develop version `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")`

Answer (score 0):

After reading this:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

The package was made to handle 50,000 points for marketClusterOptions, but only in Chrome, so I say, try using Chrome.